# First initialization of a VisitCount session gives a null pointer exception but a redeploy makes it work

Tags: session, servlets, nullpointerexception

When I initially start the tomcat Server I get a nullpointer exception referring to the line "visitCount = visitCount + 1;" And I'm not quite sure how to fix it. To my understanding it has something to do with the fact that when the session is new and it does not know what value to give back although I thought it would give 0 because of this line "Integer visitCount = new Integer(0);"

Redeploying makes the nullpointerexception go away. So that to me confirms my assumption explained above.

Help is greatly appreciated.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0pQD.jpg)

Servlet:

```
  private String getLogCount(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            Date createTime = new Date(session.getCreationTime());
            Date getLastAccesTime = new Date(session.getLastAccessedTime());
    
            String titleKey;
            Integer visitCount = new Integer(0);
            String visitCountKey = new String("visitCount");
    
    
            if (session.isNew()) {
                titleKey = "Welkom!";
    
    
            } else {
                titleKey = "Welkom terug!";
                visitCount = (Integer) session.getAttribute(visitCountKey);
                visitCount = visitCount + 1;
    
    
    
            }
            session.setAttribute(visitCountKey,  visitCount);
            session.setAttribute("createTime", createTime);
            session.setAttribute("lastAccessTime", getLastAccesTime);
            session.setAttribute("title", titleKey);
    
            return "activiteit.jsp";
        }
```

JSP PAGE:

```
 <h1 class="explanation">${title}</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Aantal keren deze website bezocht: ${visitCount}</th>
                <th>Eerste moment van je sessie: ${createTime}</th>
                <th>Laatste moment van je sessie: ${lastAccessTime}</th>
            </tr>
    
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> [..] although I thought it would give 0 because of this line `Integer visitCount = new Integer(0);`

That line of code ends up doing nothing because a few lines below you override it with this:

```
visitCount = (Integer) session.getAttribute(visitCountKey);
```

So now, `visitCount` has whatever value you extract from the session. Based on the error you are describing, you most likely retrieve null from the session.

So basically, your code does this:

```
Integer visitCount = new Integer(0);  // value is 0
// ...
visitCount = (Integer) session.getAttribute(visitCountKey); // value is whatever you get from session, most likely null based on the error you get
visitCount = visitCount + 1; // this can result in null + 1, thus your error
```

I would rewrite the code like this:

```
private String getLogCount(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    Date createTime = new Date(session.getCreationTime());
    Date getLastAccesTime = new Date(session.getLastAccessedTime());

    String titleKey;
    int visitCount = 0;
    String visitCountKey = "visitCount";

    if (session.isNew()) {
        titleKey = "Welkom!";
        
    } else {
        titleKey = "Welkom terug!";
        Integer sessionVisitCount = (Integer) session.getAttribute(visitCountKey);
        if (sessionVisitCount != null) {
            visitCount = sessionVisitCount.intValue() + 1;
        }
    }

    session.setAttribute(visitCountKey, Integer.valueOf(visitCount));
    session.setAttribute("createTime", createTime);
    session.setAttribute("lastAccessTime", getLastAccesTime);
    session.setAttribute("title", titleKey);

    return "activiteit.jsp";
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks man! Great explanation, that makes alot of sense.